# DOM IDBDatabase Exception 3 when using indexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

I'm trying something like

```
var store = trans.objectStore("todo");
```

which gives in the console the following erropr

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 3
```

Although I expect this error (the object store doesn't exist) but I want to catch it. I tried to add an onerror to the transaction

```
trans.onerror = function(e) { ... }
```

but the onerror is not called. Is there any way to catch this error using onerror? Or is the only way to wrap it with try/catch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to catch that exception? before you call the store, you can check in the database if an object stored with that name exists.

```
trans.db.objectStoreNames.contains("todo");
```

If you want to work with exceptions, it's bad for performance.

Answer (score 2):

The `onerror` handlers are for asynchronous calls. `objectStore` is one of the few synchronous calls in the API so you'll have to use a traditional `try..catch(e)`.

```
var store;
try { 
   store = trans.objectStore("todo");
} catch( err ) {
   console.log("CAUGHT", err);
}
```

Comment: you really made my day, thnx!

Comment: Where exactly is this described ? And I get the feeling that objectStore.add is also synchronious! which is probably the reason trans.oncomplete doesn't fire!

Comment: Looks like it. Check out the exceptions listed here: http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBObjectStore-add-IDBRequest-any-value-any-key  >> I should make a list of all the sync methods in the API. It is confusing. Another one is createObjectStore().